# How can make search key and merge data using for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

I tried to merge two files.
I want to find same text Aliase on b.txt match on Alias1 on a.txt.
I want to see below result:

```
VNX7600SPB3_8B3_H1;VNX7600SPB3;39;vv:06:01:xx:08:60:xx:78;8B3_H1;1
VNX7600SPBA_8B4_H1;VNX7600SPA3;35;xx:06:01:vv:08:60:vv:78;8B4_H1;2
CX480SPA1_11B3_H1;CX480SPA1;N/A;11B3_H1;
CX480SPB1_11B4_H1;CX480SPB1;N/A;11B4_H1;
```

But now myscript result is below:

```
VNX7600SPB3_8B3_H1;VNX7600SPB3;39;vv:06:01:xx:08:60:xx:78;8B3_H1;
VNX7600SPB3_8B3_H1;VNX7600SPB3;N/A;8B3_H1;
CX480SPB1_11B4_H1;CX480SPB1;N/A;11B4_H1;
CX480SPB1_11B4_H1;CX480SPB1;N/A;11B4_H1;
VNX7600SPBA_8B4_H1;VNX7600SPA3;N/A;8B4_H1;
VNX7600SPBA_8B4_H1;VNX7600SPA3;35;xx:06:01:vv:08:60:vv:78;8B4_H1;
CX480SPA1_11B3_H1;CX480SPA1;N/A;11B3_H1;
CX480SPA1_11B3_H1;CX480SPA1;N/A;11B3_H1;
```

A.txt file has the data below:

```
Zone,Alias1,Alias2
VNX7600SPB3_8B3_H1,VNX7600SPB3,8B3_H1
VNX7600SPBA_8B4_H1,VNX7600SPA3,8B4_H1
CX480SPA1_11B3_H1,CX480SPA1,11B3_H1
CX480SPB1_11B4_H1,CX480SPB1,11B4_H1
```

B.txt file has the data below:

```
WWN,Port,Aliase
xx:06:01:vv:08:60:vv:78,35,VNX7600SPA3
vv:06:01:xx:08:60:xx:78,39,VNX7600SPB3
```

I can't make the correct result.
I just begin python study. please help me.

Here is my script too:

```
f = open('b.txt', 'r')
dict = {}
next(f)
i=0
for line in f:
        i += 1
        line = line.split(',')
        line = (line[2].replace('\n','') +',' + line[1] + ";" + line[0]).strip()
        if line.startswith(",") == 1:
                line = str("Blank") + str(i) + line
        else:
                line = line

        k, v = line.strip().split(',')
        dict[k.strip()] = v.strip()
f.close()


f = open('a.txt','r')
next(f)
with open('result.txt','w') as s:
        for lines in f.xreadlines():
                lines = lines.split(',')
                zone = lines[0]
                ali1 = lines[1]
                ali2 = lines[2].replace('\n','')

##I think below line make same line and no need line


                for eachkey in dict.keys():
                        if eachkey in ali1:
                                result = zone + ";" + ali1 + ";" + dict[eachkey] + ";" + ali2 + ";"

                        elif eachkey not in ali1:
                                result = zone + ";" + ali1 + ";" + "N/A"  + ";" + ali2 + ";"
                        else:
                                continue
                        s.write(result + '\n')

s.close()
```

Comment: Do you _have_ to use loops? This problem can be solved in three lines with pandas.

Comment: could you write pandas example using my text data?

Comment: The problem is likely your second loop, for eachkey in dict.keys(). Each line of a.txt can generate up to two lines in the result. Can you post the wrong result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Merge two DataFrames without some columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450280/pandas-merge-two-dataframes-without-some-columns)

Comment: my question not correctly same that question. my question is about find and merge.